# How to create event handler for COM object when using DLR (dynamic) and no type library?

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic, com

I try to avoid using Type Libraries for COM automation with C#, but instead using the dynamic keyword to resolve types at runtime.
This works fine, except when trying to define event handler.

I've tried to define it this way:

```
_COMObject.OnStop += new Action(OnStop);
```

The original COM object however defines its ownEventHandler type with no arguments and no return value.
Thus of course Action is not the same type then and this results in a RuntimeBinderException stating that it can not convert the Action type to the ComObjectCustomEventHandler although they have the same signature.

I would need to have something like a dynamic delegate, however I haven't figured out how to define it.

Comment: If it has no return value then it is impossible, it must return HRESULT to support late binding.  Sounds pretty unlikely btw, programmers very rarely get this wrong.  Use Oleview.exe, File + View Typelib command and show us the interface.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes you are right it is defined as `HRESULT OnStop();`

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out how to do it with reflection.
I've defined the following helper method:

```
private void AddEventHandler(string eventName, Delegate method)
{
        EventInfo eInfo = _COMObject.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);

        MethodInfo evHandler = method.GetMethodInfo(); 
        Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eInfo.EventHandlerType, this, evHandler);
        eInfo.AddEventHandler(_COMobject, del);

}
```

Now I can call this method to add an event handler to it:

```
AddEventHandler("OnStop", new Action(OnStop));
```